# A proof of Riesz's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove Riesz's lemma. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a normed linear space and $M$ a closed proper subspace of $E$. Let $0 < \alpha < 1$. Then there exists an $x \in E$ with $|x|=1$ such that $|x-y| \ge \alpha$ for all $y \in M$.

**Proof:** Assume the contrary that $$\exists \alpha \in (0, 1), \forall x\in E, \exists y \in M: \left | \frac{x}{|x|}-y \right | < \alpha.$$ This is equivalent to $$\exists \alpha \in (0, 1), \forall x\in E\setminus \{0\}, \exists y \in M: \big | x - |x|y \big | < \alpha|x|.$$

Because $M$ is a proper subset of $E$, there exists some $x_0 \in M^c$. We pick $y_0 \in M$ such that $\big | x_0 - |x_0| y_0 \big | < \alpha|x_0|$. Let $x_1 := x_0 - |x_0| y_0$. Again, we pick $y_1 \in M$ such that $\big | x_1 - |x_1| y_1 \big | < \alpha|x_1|$. Recursively, $$x_{n} := x_{n-1} - |x_{n-1}|y_{n-1} \quad \text{and}\ \quad \big | x_n - |x_n| y_n \big | < \alpha|x_n| \quad \text{and} \quad y_n \in M.$$

It follows that $$\big | x_n - |x_n| y_n \big | < \alpha|x_n| <\alpha^2 |x_{n-1}| < \cdots < \alpha^{n+1} |a|.$$

This implies $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( x_n - |x_n| y_n \right ) = 0.$$

On the other hand,$$ \begin{aligned}
x_1 &= x_0 - |x_0| y_0 \\
x_1 - |x_1| y_1 &= (x_0 - |x_0| y_0) - |x_1| y_1 \\
 &= x_0 - (|x_0| y_0 + |x_1| y_1) \\
x_2 - |x_2| y_2 &= (x_1 - |x_1| y_1) - |x_2|y_2 \\
&= x_0 - (|x_0| y_0 + |x_1| y_1 + |x_2|y_2) \\
x_n - |x_n| y_n  &= x_0 - (|x_0| y_0 + \cdots + |x_n|y_n).
\end{aligned}$$

As such, $$x_0=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|y_n.$$

Because $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $E$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|y_n \in M$ and thus $x_0 \in M$. This is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks ok to me, but you need to exclude $x\ne 0$ in the first quantor as well. I'll look again tomorrow when I'm fresh but I think for the rest it's perfect!